# Find all natural numbers $m,n$ such that $m|12n-1$ and $n|12m-1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers $m,n$ such that $m|12n-1$ and $n|12m-1$

My progress:
$m,n $ must be coprime.

Also, look  at the expression $12(m+n)-1$ it is divisible by both $m,n$

Comment: The term $12(m+n)-1$ is divisible by $mn$. I've found, by the way, that $1,11$ satisfies your conditions, and so do $23,25$ ,and so do $155,13$, but I think it stops there.

Comment: $$ab=143$$  $$n=a+12$$ $$m=b+12$$

Comment: @individ That is nice insight. But are these the only possibilities?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Your comment is indeed useful, as I used it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @user21820 I've gone further, these are the only possibilities as it stands.

Comment: And these give the possibilities I had listed earlier. Excellent, it's worked out. Suppose instead of $12$, we had some $l$, then it's about looking at the factors of $l^2-1$, right? Next question, what if we have $x | 12y-1$, $y | 12z-1$ and $z | 12x-1$? That would make things interesting.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Hmm I don't know.. Anyway I made another silly mistake in my answer. After fixing it I need the bound on $k$ and more cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first observation is very useful, that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

The first comment was also very useful, that $m,n \mid 12(m+n)-1$ and hence by the above observation $mn \mid 12(m+n)-1$.

Thus $12(m+n)-1 = kmn$ for some natural $k$, and hence $(km-12)(kn-12) = 144-k$.

Note that $k$ is not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Since $m,n > 0$ we have $144 > (km-12)(kn-12) \ge (k-12)^2$ and hence $k-12 < 12$.

We now have to check all natural $k$ from $1$ to $23$ that are coprime to $2$ and $3$.

I did a quick check and I think the only solution not mentioned in the first comment comes from $k = 23$ where $(23m-12)(23n-12) = 121$ gives $(m,n) = (1,1)$.

Comment: How can you write $(km-12)(kn-12)$? there is no $k^2$ here

Comment: @AyanBiswas: Really sorry stupid mistake.. I multiplied by $k$ first before rearranging.. forgot the $-1$ becomes $-k$. Now should be correct. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @AyanBiswas: So you got it now?

Comment: Yes,great solution user21820

Comment: @AyanBiswas: Great! You can accept the answer once you're satisfied with it. =)

Answer (score 1):

We can write that, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$12n-1=ma$$ and $$12m-1=nb$$

Or we can say that, $$12mn-m=m^2a$$ and $$12mn-n=n^2b$$
Thus we get that
$$m^2a+m=n^2b+n$$ or $$m(ma+1)=n(nb+1)$$

Since we have already found out that $m,n$ are co-prime, observe that from the above relation,we get 
$$m|(nb+1)$$ and $$n|(ma+1)$$ Or, in other words,
$$nb \equiv -1 \pmod m$$ and $$ma \equiv -1 \pmod n$$

See if this helps in simplifying the problem.

**P.S.** This is not a complete solution but it may help you to progress a bit. It was just *too long* for a comment.